# C++ methods in object or static

Tags: c++, object

So C++ supports object orientation but doesn't force one to use it.
 And lets make an example:
We have a class Fruit with some complex data in it. And we want to calculate the calories

Option 1:
We put the method directly in the class:
`public: 
    int calculateCalories();`

Option 2:
We put it in Fruit.cpp but not in the class itself:
`int calculateCalories(Fruit f);`

-> What is considered to be better pratice?

Comment: In second case you would need to use `extern` to use this function from other files. Also it takes `f` by copy.

Comment: Depends on requirements, analysis, design and use-cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is considered to be better pratice?

If a function can be implemented as a non-member function using the existing `public` member functions of the class, it is better to make it a non-member function.

See [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) if you can find some time. It's a bit lengthy.

Simple example:

```
class Circle
{
   public:
      Circle(double r = 0) : radius(r) {}

      double getRadius() const { return radius; }

   priviate:
      double radius;
};
```

Given the above, it is possible to implement functions to compute the area and circumference of a circle using non-member functions.

```
double area(Circle const& c)
{
   double r = c.getRadius();
   return M_PI*r*r;
}

double circumference(Circle const& c)
{
   double r = c.getRadius();
   return 2*M_PI*r;
}
```

According to the above article, it is better to implement these functions as non-member functions since they can be implemented using the existing `public` interface of `Circle`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Any function can be implemented as a non-member function.

Comment: I'll add to my answer later to elaborate on the topic. I'm going to bed now.

Comment: @super - that's not true.   It is not possible to have a non-friend non-member function that can directly (as in, without going via some intermediary) access any private members of a class without relying on undefined behaviour or compiler extensions.

Comment: @Peter I don't see non-friend specified anywhere. You could also add a getter and that way get around it. The point is that the answer is not specific enough to give any value unless you already know the answer.

Comment: @super - you made a statement that was false.  I provided a counter example, and you respond by imposing extra conditions - a getter and setter is an intermediary.   In any event, the fact you are not understanding the answer doesn't mean it is wrong.  You need to read AND comprehend the link given to understand.

Comment: @Peter Really? You are the one who added the condition non-friend to make my statement false. Also, link only answers are not considered valid here on SO.

Comment: @super - You said "Any function can be implemented as a non-member function".   That is a pretty broad statement and, if it was true, no conditions could be found that make it false.   I provided a counter-example by specifying a set of  conditions in which your statement is actually false.   There are others

Comment: @Peter By that logic "Fish can swim in water" would be false since if the water is frozen, fish could not swim in it. You are making no sense, and more importantly, your argument is out of context with the actual question and answer presented and brings no additional value or clarification. Are you having a bad day or something?

Comment: @super, I expanded the answer a little bit. Hope it makes more sense now.